# Joins with LAZY mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Simple question that I could not find answer yet.

If I have entity A that has a relationship with B and C with a CascadeType.ALL. And then I modify A, and save it.

Then in the query, Hibernate does the join table with B and C, if those mappings are declared as LAZY?. Entities B and C has not change at all, so we should have the Hibernate proxy for those entities.

But when I see the log file, I can see "left outer join" for between A with B and C.

I´m having an issue in MySQL because max number of joins(61) allowed.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

> Your question is not clear!

*Assuming you are asking- You have a entity **A** which have relationship with **B** and **C**. If you update and save A, will B and C will be saved automatically?*

If it's the case what need is proper cascading type.

If you want entity **B** and **C** to be saved when **A** is saved then you need **cascade = CascadeType.UPDATE**

```
A {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.Update, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    B b;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I fully understand the Cascade principle. But my question was, if A is edited but only A, and B and C remain intact as Hibernate proxy objects. It will Hibernate make a join with B and C tables?

Comment: Can you please clarify " makes a join"

Comment: Since B and C has A because of the relationship with Foreign key, if B and C will make the join table with A, when A will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear

If you want to know whether hibernate updates (B and C) or not when updating A ? The answer is NO if your cascade is not set to UPDATE or SAVE_UPDATE. (the id of A doesn't change).

In addition to that, since your fetch is LAZY, you can't modify C and B

Comment: I recreate my question. Sorry I agree that was not clean enough

Comment: @paul : If associations with B and C are declared LAZY, when you Load your entity A, the associations are not loaded, B and C are not loaded (just proxies), if you update A, hibernate will update A only. B and C will not be updated, the SQL generated doesn't contain any join to B and C

Comment: Do you know where can I found documentation about the fact that then, with Lazy relationship there´s no 'left outer join' when a proxy is not initialize. I still seeing the select and left outer join in hibernate logs.

Comment: I have tried it. I don't know where to find that, read the documentation of hibernate.

Comment: That´s why I did. But I could not find anything either